# How do Bible scholars interpret Mtt 11:25?

Tags: matthew, revelation, mystery

We read in Mtt 11:25 (KJV):

> At that time Jesus answered and said, I thank thee, O Father, Lord of heaven and earth, because thou hast hid these things from the wise and prudent, and hast revealed them unto babes.

One peculiar thing about the wise and prudent men is that they ignore the simple and straightforward meaning of the scriptures and look for complicated interpretations with the sheer intention of making others appreciate their thought . Their scrupulosity in adhering to the nitty gritties of law in total negation of the actual intent, came for sharp criticism from Jesus (Mtt 23:23 ) A childlike attitude to the law in particular and the scriptures as a whole, is what Jesus recommended. But his thanking of the Father makes one doubt if there was a pro-active role from the side of the Father in making the wise & prudent unable to comprehend the Divine Mysteries.  So, how do Bible scholars interpret Mtt 11:25 ?

Comment: See https://biblehub.com/commentaries/matthew/11-25.htm   Can you be any more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Paul explains it here...

**1 Corinthians 1:17-31**

> "For Christ sent me not to baptize, but to preach the gospel: not with wisdom of words, lest the cross of Christ should be made of none effect.
> 18 For the preaching of the cross is to them that perish foolishness; but unto us which are saved it is the power of God.
> 19 For it is written, I will destroy the wisdom of the wise, and will bring to nothing the understanding of the prudent.
> 20 Where is the wise? where is the scribe? where is the disputer of this world? hath not God made foolish the wisdom of this world?
> 21 For after that in the wisdom of God the world by wisdom knew not God, it pleased God by the foolishness of preaching to save them that believe.
> 22 For the Jews require a sign, and the Greeks seek after wisdom:
> 23 But we preach Christ crucified, unto the Jews a stumblingblock, and unto the Greeks foolishness;
> 24 But unto them which are called, both Jews and Greeks, Christ the power of God, and the wisdom of God.
> 25 Because the foolishness of God is wiser than men; and the weakness of God is stronger than men.
> 26 For ye see your calling, brethren, how that not many wise men after the flesh, not many mighty, not many noble, are called:
> 27 But God hath chosen the foolish things of the world to confound the wise; and God hath chosen the weak things of the world to confound the things which are mighty;
> 28 And base things of the world, and things which are despised, hath God chosen, yea, and things which are not, to bring to nought things that are:
> 29 That no flesh should glory in his presence.
> 30 But of him are ye in Christ Jesus, who of God is made unto us wisdom, and righteousness, and sanctification, and redemption:
> 31 That, according as it is written, He that glorieth, let him glory in the Lord."

Comment: While they do discuss related topics, we do prefer for texts to first be investigated in their own rights, before bringing in intertextual links. Matthew was an Apostle after all, and he wrote his gospel to be understood by itself, without needing to read Paul's letters first. And in addition, we need answers to explain their interpretation, not just quote other verses. Please see [What are we looking for in answers?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/520/2757) [What does "show your work" mean in the context of exegesis?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536/2757)

Comment: We are actually commanded to compare scripture with scripture...not scripture with man's "wisdom": 1 Corinthians 2:12-14  "Now we have received, not the spirit of the world, but the spirit which is of God; that we might know the things that are freely given to us of God.
13 Which things also we speak, not in the words which man's wisdom teacheth, but which the Holy Ghost teacheth; comparing spiritual things with spiritual.
14 But the natural man receiveth not the things of the Spirit of God: for they are foolishness unto him: neither can he know them, because they are spiritually discerned."

Answer (score 1):

Matthew 11:25 NIV

> At that time Jesus said, “I praise you, Father, Lord of heaven and earth, because **you have hidden these things from the wise and learned, and revealed them to little children.**

In Matthew 18:1-5, Jesus conveys a profound metaphor explaining why someone must embrace childlike qualities to enter the kingdom of heaven.

> 1 At that time the disciples came to Jesus and asked, “Who, then, is the greatest in the kingdom of heaven?” 2 He called a little child to him, and placed the child among them. 3 And he said: “Truly I tell you, unless you change and become like little children, you will never enter the kingdom of heaven. 4 **Therefore, whoever takes the lowly position of this child is the greatest in the kingdom of heaven.** 5 And whoever welcomes one such child in my name welcomes me.

Therefore, the ability to perceive the kingdom of heaven is not contingent upon a person's knowledge or actual age, but rather on their mindset. Those who willingly assume a humble and lowly position open themselves to receive guidance from the Holy Spirit. In contrast, the wise often take pride in their own capabilities, rendering them unable to submit to the Holy Spirit's leading. It is not that the Lord intentionally hides things from them; rather, their pride becomes the obstacle. Jesus did not withhold information from the Pharisees; but rather, it was their offense at His teaching that led Jesus to comment on their spiritual blindness in Matthew 15:14;

> "Leave them; they are blind guides. If the blind lead the blind, both will fall into a pit.”